# Skip in SQL Server subquery

Tags: sql-server

I want to use left outer join like this:

```
    SELECT ...
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT only e.g. 3rd record... , SomeField FROM Table2) tbl2
  ON Table1.SomeField = tbl2.SomeField
```

How can I do that, if I need the subquery to select not just the 3rd record from Table2, but the 3rd record among the Table2 records that have SomeField = Table1.SomeField?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "3rd record"? Resuts sets don't have an order unless you have an ORDER BY clause. Your example doesn't have one  though. Could you make your example more clear?

Comment: Can you please post the table structures, the query you tried and what the result **should** look like?

Comment: The real task is to move data from two Table1 and Table2 into Table3. The target Table3 has Field1, Field2, and Field3, and I need Field1 have data from Table2.SomeField (1st record), Field2 - from Table2.SomeField (2nd record), and Field3 - from Table2.SomeField (3rd record). So I am trying to left outer join Table1 with Table2 3 times, but selecting different records: 1st, 2nd, and 3rd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is sql server 2005 or newer, you might use [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
LEFT JOIN
(
   select *
     from
     (
       select *,
              row_number() over (order by something) rn
         from Table2
        where Table2.Column = Table1.Column
     ) a
    where a.rn = 3
) a
```

Unfortunately you need to nest it a level deeper because you cannot use row_number in a condition directly.

**EDIT:**

My bad - i didn't really notice the join part. If you want to join derived table, use this:

```
LEFT JOIN
(
   select *,
          row_number() over (partition by SomeField order by something) rn
     from Table2
) tbl2
  ON Table1.SomeField = tbl2.SomeField
 AND tbl2.rn = 3
```

Note: you need ORDER BY in row_number() to keep things consistent.

Comment: "you cannot use row_number at the same place where you define it" you can order by row_number directly.

Comment: @tim Yes, it is very true. I ment one cannot use it in a condition.

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried this solution, but got an error: The multi-part identifier "Table1.Column" could not be bound.

Comment: @DavidShochet Please check EDIT section of my answer.

Comment: @DavidShochet And changed again - added `partition by` part.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to be working. Could you please just tell me how to order by row_number? Is it like this: "partition by SomeField order by Row_Number()"?

Comment: @DavidShochet No, order by something is how would you determine which row is first, which second and which third; for example, if you have a date column `x` simply put order by x to get row 1 with lowest date etc.

Comment: @DavidShochet I suppose the biggest question is how you determine which row is which. Could you please explain that part?

Comment: It must sound silly, but for now that table has no primary key, so I just need to get data from 3 records of one table and insert it into 3 fields of another table (see my explanation in a comment to my original question)

Comment: @DavidShochet If it is completely random, remove the order by part of `row_number() over ()`. I just wish there would be something distinct (a date, timestamp, a group of referenced ids) that would determine the order if you need to run this query multiple times.